# ¿Es posible añadir un botón al reproductor de video para mostrar texto de un archivo .txt en swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, video

Me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación en Swift 3 en la que se requiere una lista de videos y cada uno carga de un texto de ayuda dentro del video, este se puede mostrar u ocultar mediante un botón en la barra de reproducción.

He estado probado algo similar a esto, sin resultados.

```
let subtitleFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video_N", ofType: "txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Si usas el reproductor nativo de ios te diré que no es posible añadir un botón , tienes dos opciones:

```
-Buscar un reproductor hecho por alguien que solucione tus problemas en github
-Utiliza el reproductor nativo y oculta la barra de control , añade una vista por encima del visor del video que simule que es la barra de control del reproductor y que será totalmente personalizada por ti.
```